# How to solve resume from suspend on MBP 2,1 17" 2006

Tags: power

Had to remove all of the Power settings related to resume (to 'do nothing') on my machine due to suspend not waking machine properly. Screen remains black.

Note: sometimes MacOS SnowLeopard did have the issue that the screen did not wake, but a re-suspend re-wake did solve the matter everytime.

Using loki 0.4.1; graphic card is ATI Mobility Radeon X1600 - does it has to do with installing the proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is now solved: first I followed these two tutorials:
1. [Improving Power management in EOS Freya](https://adam.merrifield.ca/2015/11/25/improving-power-management-in-eos-freya/) (though using Loki 0.4.1)
2. [Most Effective Ways to Reduce Laptop Overheating in Linux](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/)

Then I had a system update (drivers and intel chip) and since then resume from Suspend is going rather smoothly, and also lid close to Suspend goes fine too now.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for posting a fix. I had a hell of a time trying to track this stuff down and just gave up. It's appreciated! :)

Comment: I've noticed something related to DVD playback, though: when there's been a full screen playback, sometimes Suspend won't work properly and will do just like before, produce a black screen and require a force reboot..

Comment: Yeah, I don't bother with such things with computers. I just keep things on or off Linux or Windows. I don't do the suspend/hibernate options anymore.

Comment: System's just fine now, suspends comprehensively, including on lid close and resumes most of the time normally too.